# Android In-app billing dialog overrides activity orientation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, in-app-billing

I have an app which runs in portrait-only mode. Recently I've added in-app purchasing.

To do that I've created a service which starts purchase dialog (The Android SDK provides it).

As I understand it, my service sends an intent and somewhere inside the Android activity receives this intent and shows a dialog on the top of my activity stack.

When the dialog is shown it overrides(???) orientation of all activities in the stack!

How can I fix it?

Comment: It's the Android Market that receives the intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering the exact same thing. I investigated and looks like this is a known bug. The only workaround I can suggest is to have a black view filling the screen in front of your actual content for the duration of the in-app purchase popup.